# What are the differences in using qasm, statevector, and unitary simulators in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, qasm

From my understanding statevector is a more simplistic using vector space, qasm is supposed to introduce noise like running it on an actual quantum computer. What types of problems would you use one simulator over another? I am not too familiar with unitary simulators as the class I took mostly covered qasm and statevector.

Answer (score 4):

They all produce different types of result. Let's go one by one:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
```

### Unitary Simulator

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: bell state]

```
unitary_simulator = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
unitary_simulator_result = unitary_simulator.run(circuit).result()
unitary_simulator_result.data()
```

```
{'unitary': Operator([[ ...
}
```

The result is an [`Operator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Operator.html). It can be printed nicely like this:

```
array_to_latex(unitary_simulator_result.get_unitary())
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
 \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

It is useful, for example, when you want to set some unitary at arbitrary point of the execution:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.set_unitary(random_unitary(4))
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
unitary_simulator_result = unitary_simulator.run(circuit).result()
unitary_simulator_result.get_unitary()
```

### Statevector Simulator

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)

statevector_simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
statevector_simulator_result = statevector_simulator.run(circuit).result()
statevector_simulator_result.data()
```

```
{'statevector': Statevector([ ...
}
```

The result is a [`Statevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html). It can be printed nicely like this:

```
array_to_latex(statevector_simulator_result.get_statevector())
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

It can be useful, for example, to make snapshots during different points of the execution:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.save_statevector('breakpoint')
circuit.cx(0, 1)

statevector_simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
statevector_simulator_result = statevector_simulator.run(circuit).result()
array_to_latex(statevector_simulator_result.data()['breakpoint'])
```

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

### QASM Simulator

Needs measurments, as it simulates an idea (**without noise**, by default) quantum hardware.

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.measure_all()  # <--
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: bell state with measurements]

```
qasm_simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
qasm_simulator_result = qasm_simulator.run(circuit).result()
qasm_simulator_result.data()
```

```
{'counts': {'0x3': 534, '0x0': 490}}
```

The result is a Python dict. It can be printed nicely like this:

```
plot_histogram(qasm_simulator_result.get_counts())
```

[image: histogram]

With this simulator, you can simulate a executions in shots and get the value of each of them:

```
memory_result = qasm_simulator.run(circuit, shots=10, memory=True).result()
memory_result.get_memory(circuit)
```

```
['00', '00', '11', '11', '00', '00', '11', '11', '00', '00']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Statevector Simulator** - It gives the output of the circuit in the form of a statevector
2. **Qasm Simulator** - This backend simulates the execution of quantum circuits on a real noisy device.
3. **Unitary Simulator** - It gives the output of the circuit in the form of a unitary matrix.

You can use the Qiskit simulator [tutorials](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/simulators/1_aer_provider.ipynb) to learn more and explore these simulators, as well as discover new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: all three simulators are **ideal, noise-free** simulators on classical computers.

- Unitary simulator: you get a unitary matrix as result
- Statevector simulator: you get a statevector (2^qubit array) as result
- Qasm simulator: you get a measurement histogram or state dictionary as result

Qasm simulator might be the closet to a real and perfect quantum computer, which does not exist yet.